# Pass a callback as a parameter to abstract setOnClickListener in Android

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

```
 public interface Callback {
    void execute(Button button);
}

protected void addClickListener(final Button button, final Callback callback) {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callback.execute(button);
        }
    });
}

protected Callback numberActions(Button button) {
    String value = button.getText().toString();
    setDisplay(value);
}

protected void setDisplay (String value) {
        String newValue;
        displayValue = resultDisplay.getText().toString();
        if (displayValue.length() < 10){
            newValue = resultDisplay.getText() + value;
            resultDisplay.setText(newValue);
            displayValue = newValue;
        }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button numberButtons[] = new Button[11];
        numberButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberOne);
        numberButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberTwo);
        numberButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberTwo);
        numberButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberThree);
        numberButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberFour);
        numberButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberFive);
        numberButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberSix);
        numberButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberSeven);
        numberButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberEight);
        numberButtons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberNine);
        numberButtons[10] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberZero);

        resultDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultDisplay);

        for (Button button: numberButtons) {
            addClickListener(button, numberActions(button));
        }
}
```

I'm building a simple calculator on Android Studio with Java.

Instead of calling setOnClickListener to each instance of a button, I have created addClickListiner to abstract it. So for example, I create an array of number buttons and on the `onClick` function I define that they should change Input display as an action. My goal is to use addClickListener to each button, then I can pass an action as a second parameter (callback) which will define what action that button will perform.

Actually I'm a javascript developer, and that would be as simple as just passing a function as a parameter. As I'm learning Java, I don't know how to perform it... My goal is to pass a void function as a parameter to perform it whenever the button is clicked.

I have tried to create a public interface... But when I try to build it, it breaks saying that I should have a return statement on numberActions method. Can anyone help me with how to pass a callback function as params on this case?

Comment: why did you define a callback interface?

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan As I understood, that's the way to send a void function as a parameter. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: i mean why you need it in that case , is the ui you want to update is in another activity/fragment

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan No, actually it's all one the same activity. My only goal is to pass a function as a param which will define what action that button will perform

Comment: if you don't want want to set onClickListner on each button, which is not a bad idea, you can create you own Listner class and then check in it's onClick which button is pressed and to the appropriate operation accordingly

Comment: But how about my idea of isolating it in a function, which one parameter is the button itself and the other is the action, which will be called inside onClick function. Just to understand, is that a bad idea and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
for (Button button : numberButtons) {
       button.setOnClickListener = this;
}
```

Implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface. Then in your activity/fragment

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Button button= (Button) v

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.numberOne:
       String value = button.getText().toString();
       setDisplay(value);
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got what you mean, but I will have another button types, like the one to make operations, which will perform another action, different than number buttons

Comment: @asotos Put those there too. Do `button.setOnClickListener = this;` for all the buttons you need then get those action in the `onClick` method.

Comment: Nice. I will use it as my fallback option. I indeed want to perform the action as a callback, instead of iterating on a switch case method. But if i have no choice. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to pass a void function as a parameter to perform it whenever the button is clicked

You can achieve this by using a [`Consumer<Button>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/util/Consumer) as callback. If you have some action buttons (e.g. "+", "-") as well as buttons with digits then your method `numberActions()` could work like this:

```
private Consumer<Button> add = new Consumer<Button>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Button button) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "'Add' not yet implemented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

private Consumer<Button> subtract = new Consumer<Button>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Button button) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "'Subtract' not yet implemented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

protected Consumer<Button> numberActions(Button button) {
    final String value = button.getText().toString();
    switch (value){
        case "+":
            return add;
        case "-":
            return subtract;
        default: // must be a digit
            return new Consumer<Button>(){
                @Override
                public void accept(Button button) {
                    setDisplay(value);
                }
            };
    }
}
```